# Insertar registros nuevos y editar existentes SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy subiendo un excel a través de un formulario, este excel contiene registros de productos los cuales deben ser insertados en la base de datos para llevar un control de inventario en el sistema.

Me surge el problema de que necesito que al subir el excel el sistema me inserte los productos nuevos que consiga en el excel y me edite los que ya existen.

Para ello declare el campo código de la tabla productos como campo UNIQUE para poder realizar lo que menciono, al utilizar INSERT INTO productos ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE como muestro en mi código, el trabajo de actualizar existentes y insertar nuevos lo realiza bien, el problema esta en que al momento de que inserta los registros nuevos el ultimo id autoincrementable de la tabla se lo salta según la cantidad de registros que existan en la tabla. Por ejemplo:

Asi esta mi tabla con los productos existentes:

```
**id - codigo - producto - precio**
   1 -  CCC1  - samsung  - 150
   2 -  CCC2  - LG       - 120
   3 -  CCC3  - Huawei   - 150
```

Al realizar el INSERT INTO productos ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE y hay registros nuevos en el excel, la tabla queda de la siguiente manera:

```
**id - codigo - producto - precio**
   1 -  CCC1  - samsung  - 150
   2 -  CCC2  - LG       - 120
   3 -  CCC3  - Huawei   - 180
   7 -  CCC4  - Nokia    - 90
```

La función de actualizar los existentes bien y la de insertar nuevos bien, pero como pueden ver el id autoincremento en vez de insertar el numero 4, inserto el 7 y esto me genera problemas, ademas de no que no esta bien que lo deje asi.

Lo que quisiera saber es de que forma puedo hacer el proceso de actualización e inserción sin utilizar el INSERT INTO ON KEY UPDATE.

```
$sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT codigo FROM productos");
$sql->execute();
$array = $sql->fetchAll();

for($i = 13; $i <= $numRows; $i++){
    $cod = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $descri = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $uxc = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $precioA = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
                    $precioC = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $existencia = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('F'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $und = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('G'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();



   if (in_array($cod,$array)) {
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE productos SET descripcion = ?, precioA = ?, precioC = ?, uxc = ? WHERE codigo = ?");
                        $sql->execute(array($descri,$precioA,$precioC,$uxc,$cod));
                        $json['error'] = false;
   }else{
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO productos(codigo,descripcion,precioA,precioC,uxc,visible)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,1)");
        $sql->execute(array($cod,$descri,$precioA,$precioC,$uxc));
        $json['error'] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: El valor que genera el autonumérico no debería ser importante para ti. Con saber que es único y que sirve de clave primaria es suficiente. No puedes contar con que al guardar va a tener un valor determinado ya que eso lo determina la base de datos en el momento de guardar

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes consultar con:

```
$sql = $this->db->prepare("select count(*) as conteo from productos where codigo = ?");
```

Y si conteo es mayor a cero se usa *update*, en caso contrario se usa *insert*, eso evita un uso incorrecto de *insert*.

Comment: Saludos Oscar, no he entendido tu propuesta, en que parte de mi codigo deberia realizar esa query. que obtendria contando los registros de la tabla productos?

Comment: Si el conteo es mayor a cero, quiere decir que existe al menos un registro y por lo mismo se debe de editar el registro con UPDATE, en caso de que el conteo devuelva cero, quiere decir que no existen registros y por lo tanto debe insertarse un registro con INSERT.

Comment: Oscar Saludos, sigo sin entender lo que me planteas. Allí he editado la pregunta agregando como tengo el código ahora, aun utilizando esto que cambie me sigue saltando los id de la misma manera. Si puedes darme tu ejemplo basándote en mi código me seria de ayuda para entender mejor lo que me dices.